# Load classes from two versions of library depending on android version

Tags: java, android, class, import

I'm trying to use two modified Apache POI libraries. Each libray has modifications to work properly on android 4.+ and 5.+.

I need to import specific class of specific library depending on android version.

For example:

**Android 4.+ versions:**

`import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;` 
**of** 
`compile files('libs/aa-poi-3.10-min-0.1.5.jar')`

**Android 5.+ versions:**

`import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;` 
**of**
 `compile files('libs/poi-3.12-android-a.jar')`

How could i do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define two flavours

```
productFlavors {
    android4plus {
        minSdkVersion 14
    }
    android5plus {
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
}
```

Now you can setup different dependencies per flavour

```
android4plusCompile files('libs/aa-poi-3.10-min-0.1.5.jar')
android5plusCompile files('libs/poi-3.12-android-a.jar')
```

As result, you can switch between flavours during development and will have two APK files to distribute.

Comment: Can I switch beetween favours in the same APK file? For example on execution time decide if use one class which import android4plus or android5plus.

Comment: No, it is like two branches, each branch builds into separate APK. In runtime you have only one branch loaded into memory.

Comment: If you want to have both versions at runtime, make separate package name for them, like `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.android4.XSSFWorkbook` and `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.android5.XSSFWorkbook` for example.